# unable to restrict giving focus to child if clicked on parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

In [my application here](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/csTS7/196/), I am having an issue specifically with Chrome v35. It works very well with Firefox v30.

**Reproducing the problem:** Add an item. Click on the white space between the new text and star.

The focus should not go to the `contenteditable` element.
I tried:

```
$(document).on("click", "li", function(event){ 
    event.stopPropagation();                            
});
```

but it didnt help. I also played with `blur` but didnt get desired result.

How do I fix this so that the text is editable only when I click on it?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/csTS7/196/)

**EDIT 1:** This issue can be observed [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/pc2Lm/) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go, but in the future I suggest using an input, much easier to maneuver on it: http://jsfiddle.net/pc2Lm/3/

```
$('p').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('contenteditable','true');
    $(this).trigger('focus');
});
$(document).on('click',function(e){
    if (!$('p').is(e.target)    && $('p').has(e.target).length === 0){ 
        $('p').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('contenteditable','false');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: in the solution you provided, if you click on the whitespace underneath the `span`(the text) you'll see that it gets focused and gets editable, so no it isn't.

Comment: I integrated your code successfully in my project here: http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/csTS7/207/embedded/result/. Now, if you try adding multiple elements and try editing them, all of them, I get a bug on the last element which says its a duplicate even if it isnt. I think it is getting focus again.

Comment: in your fiddle I can not get the "add" button to work! please fix it so I can see the problem

Comment: p.s. my code doesn't create anything, so the duplicated element must be somewhere in your code, try double checking it!

Comment: The add button is enabled only after you add some text.

Comment: it doesn't get enabled, I even checked the checkbox and tried everything, believe me!